# Movie quality after zooming in

Tags: video-quality, zoom, video-player

My laptop screen is **1366x768p** (WXGA, 16:9).

If the player (potplayer) zooms in on a *1080p* movie (which shows upper and lower black bars) up to **125%**, what effetive quality does the movie end up being?

Comment: That really depends on your definition of quality

Comment: @stib is the movie effectively still  Full HD?

Comment: So the player is stretching the movie to fill the screen?

Comment: @stib no it's zooming in on the movie, just the opposite method

Comment: That makes no sense, unless it makes the screen physically smaller.

Comment: @stib https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0G28wjqvLQ

Comment: Yep, so it's stretching the movie to fit the screen. Since it's cropping off pixels, then you're not getting the full 1920x1080 raster. But here's the thing: on a 1366x768 screen, the highest resolution you can achieve is 1366x768.it will *never* be 1080p, there aren't enough pixels.

Comment: @stib if now the original movie is 720p, and the screen still  has a resolution 1366x768p. Is the movie still 720p after being proportionally zoomed in on up to 125%?

Comment: Well it won't have gained any extra pixels, those 720 pixels will be interpolated to fit over 768 pixels (which is usually a lossy process), and pixels from the side will be cropped. Whether you could call it 720p or not is kinda a question of semantics.